# Job for gunicorn.socket not found

Tags: django, sockets, nginx, python-3.6, gunicorn

I am trying to setup gunicorn for my django website on the digitalocean but

```
    sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
```

responds as "Job for gunicorn.socket failed".
I have double checked for any spelling mistakes or directory path issues.

I have been following this tutorial - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

filepath = /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/profile_website
ExecStart=/home/myuser/profile_website/myenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          project2.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

filepath = /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

I have already tried restarting gunicorn.socket but it did not work.

Comment: i have checked status for gunicorn
        systemctl status gunicorn.socket
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)

Comment: Is the error solved?